# What is format of Matlab pointCloud returned by reconstructScene()?

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

pointCloud = reconstructScene(disparityMap, stereoParams);

What does pointCloud represent?  What form is it in?

Doc says it's an M-by-N-by-3 array.  What is 'M' and 'N' ?

X = point3D(:, :, 1);
Y = point3D(:, :, 2);
Z = point3D(:, :, 3);
...these get the X,Y,Z for each pixel or each point in space in the disparityMap?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `reconstructScene` is indeed an M-by-N-by-3 array, where `[M,N] = size(disparityMap)`. The answer to your last question is "yes".